# IIS 7 HTTP Error log files

Tags: iis-7, http-error

I'm using Windows Azure Virtual Machine and installed IIS media services. I'm doing encoding, using Expression Encoder, on this virtual machine publish points.

This is creating too many error log files under **C:\Windows\System32\LogFiles\HTTPERR**. Which is increasing the drive size. I've to manually delete these files.

I want to stop creating these log files.

Here is what I tried:

[Help link](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/httplogging)

I run the following command in command prompt:

```
CD C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv

appcmd.exe set config "Default Web Site" -section:system.webServer/httpLogging /dontLog:"True" /commit:apphost
```

Result:

```
C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv>appcmd.exe set config "Default Web Site" -section:sy
stem.webServer/httpLogging /dontLog:"True" /commit:apphost
Applied configuration changes to section "system.webServer/httpLogging" for "MAC
HINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/Default Web Site" at configuration commit path "MACHINE/WEB
ROOT/APPHOST"
```

Sample text from http error file [file size is **1 MB**]:

```
#Software: Microsoft HTTP API 2.0
#Version: 1.0
#Date: 2013-07-09 11:35:50
#Fields: date time c-ip c-port s-ip s-port cs-version cs-method cs-uri sc-status s-siteid s-reason s-queuename
2013-07-09 11:35:50 168.62.194.141 57005 10.146.242.42 80 HTTP/1.1 POST /PP/TEST.isml/Streams(Encoder1) - 1 Request_Cancelled ASP.NET+v4.0
2013-07-09 11:35:50 168.62.194.141 57007 10.146.242.42 80 HTTP/1.1 POST /PP/TEST.isml/Streams(Encoder1) - 1 Request_Cancelled ASP.NET+v4.0
2013-07-09 11:35:50 168.62.194.141 56033 10.146.242.42 80 HTTP/1.1 POST /PP/TEST.isml/Streams(Encoder1) - 1 Request_Cancelled ASP.NET+v4.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't seen that command ... so I don't know if that will work ... but this should work ...

http://support.microsoft.com/?id=820729

Comment: Hey! I tried it before posting here but that time I used the "**Fix it for me: Disable HTTP API error logging**" tool and it stopped my IIS and IIS Media Services, so I undo this. But this time I go with "**Let me fix it myself**" option and it worked for me. :) Thank you so much for this [link](http://support.microsoft.com/?id=820729&wa=wsignin1.0#LetMeFixItMyselfAlways).

Comment: Link broken for some reason , can be found here : http://support.microsoft.com/kb/820729/en-us#LetMeFixItMyselfAlways